# Decreasing the time necessary to enter the coefficients of a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, compiler-optimization

Using Python, I want to build a square matrix whose coefficients are functions evaluated at some given points. The matrix is lower triangular, yet it takes more than 200 seconds to enter all the coefficients when the size is 1000. This is quite surprising to me as I have already dealt with square matrices of size greater than 1 million.

I guess that the loss of time comes from the function that defines all the non-zero coefficients of the matrix: it is a product of four terms, each of them involving a complex power (see the minimal example below).
I would be really happy if someone could help me: the purpose is to reach a size of 1 million within a few seconds (hope this is doable...). Maybe the use of ** is not optimal for the complex power; or maybe there is a quicker way to fill a lower triangular matrix? Any help will be appreciated!

For the code below, Ns is the size of the square matrix.

```
import math
from math import *
import numpy as np
from numpy import exp, log, sqrt, cos, sin, arange
import time


tmps1 = time.time()


Ns = 100
h = 1/float(Ns)
Ns = int(Ns)

mu = 0.01

rn = -6.34
rc = 0.86
r1 = 1.32
r2 = 4.16

P = np.zeros((Ns + 1, 1))
for j in range(0, Ns + 1):
    P[j] = r1 + j*(r2-r1)*h

kappan = 0.24
kappac = -0.24
kappa1 = 0.095
kappa2 = -0.095


z = complex(0.01,0.01)


def E(exponent,p):
    return (  ( ((p-rn)/(2-rn))**((exponent)/(2*kappan)) )*( ((p-rc)/(2-rc))**((exponent)/(2*kappac)) )*( ((p-r1)/(2-r1))**((exponent)/(2*kappa1)) )*( ((r2-p)/(r2-2))**((exponent)/(2*kappa2)) )  )

def D(p,r):
    return (      ( 1/(2*complex(0.0,1.0)*(z-mu/r1)) )*(   ( 1/(2*(kappa1-complex(0.0,1.0)*(z-mu/r1))) )*( E(2*(kappa1-complex(0.0,1.0)*(z-mu/r1)),r)*E(2*complex(0.0,1.0)*(z-mu/r1),p) )   -   ( 1/(2*kappa1) )*E(2*kappa1,r)   )      )


A = np.zeros((Ns-1, Ns-1), dtype=np.complex_)

for j in range(1, Ns-1):
    for k in range(1, j+1):
        A[j,k] = D(P[j+1], P[k+1]) - D(P[j+1], P[k])


tmps2 = time.time()-tmps1
print "\n\nExecution time = %f\n\n" %tmps2
```

Comment: You may try to vectorize the computation rather than using explicit for-loops with `numpy`.

Comment: @GZ0 I do not catch what you exactly mean, could you elaborate a little bit please ?

Comment: [This post](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/09/going-faster-with-numpy.html) provides a basic introduction.

Comment: You can easily speed up your code by 2x by noting that inside the inner loop on 2nd and every subsequent iteration the value of the term `D(P[j+1], P[k])` is equal to the value of the term `D(P[j+1], P[k+1])` from the previous iteration.

Comment: The next step is to note that inside the inner loop only the second argument to the function `D()` varies. Therefore you can refactor your code in such a way that all subexpressions that depend only on the first argument of `D()` are computed only once (per each iteration of the outer loop). This should give you another 30% performance improvement.

Comment: For `Ns = 1000`, I get *65s*. What is the final goal?

Comment: @CristiFati Well this is not the true code but a simplified version of it. Say that I would like to decrease at the maximum the the time needed for the execution. For example, if you can improve the code so that you end for Ns = 1000 with 0.65s, it will be great!

Comment: Is Cython or Numba not an option? This would speed up the calculation by at least two orders of magnitude. There is only a bit of rewriting necessary (no global variables)

Answer (score 5):

### Optimization, Round-1:

Avoid recomputation of D.

```
d = np.zeros((Ns+1, Ns+1), dtype=np.complex_)
for j in range(2, Ns):
    for k in range(1, j+1):
        d[j,k] = D(P[j], P[k])

A = np.zeros((Ns-1, Ns-1), dtype=np.complex_)
for j in range(1, Ns-1):
    for k in range(1, j+1):
        A[j,k] = d[j+1, k+1] - d[j+1, k]
```

Reduces time to half

### Optimization, Round-2:

Vectorized the computation of D.
Replace computation of d with:

```
d = np.zeros((Ns, Ns), dtype=np.complex_)
for shift in range(0, Ns-1):
    x = D(P, np.roll(P,shift))
    for j in range(shift+1, Ns):
        d[j,j-shift] = x[j]
```

### Optimization, Round-3:

Vectorized the computation of A.
Replace the computation of A with:

```
d = np.roll(d, -1, axis=(0,1))
A = d - np.roll(d, 1, axis=1)
A *= np.tri(*A.shape)
```

Takes around **1.2 seconds for Ns=1000**

Edit:

### Round-4:

```
P = np.fromfunction(lambda j, i: r1 + j*(r2-r1)*h, (Ns+1, 1), dtype=float)
Q = np.fromfunction(lambda j, i: r1 + ((j-i)%(Ns+1))*(r2-r1)*h, (Ns+1, Ns), dtype=float)
# P = Q[:,0].reshape(11,1)
d = D(P, Q)
d = np.fromfunction(lambda r, c: d[r,(r-c)], (Ns,Ns), dtype=int)

d = np.roll(d, -1, axis=(0,1))
A = d - np.roll(d, 1, axis=1)
A = np.tril(A)
```

Thanks Fabio Lipreri for suggestion of `fromfunction`, I have exploited it to the hilt!

**Time Taken: 400ms**, for Ns=1000

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the previous answer of ckedar, you can speed up a little by improving the calculation of P vector using numpy vectorization. In the following code I used numpy's `fromfunction` function:

```
const = (r2-r1)*h
P = np.fromfunction(lambda j, i: r1 + j*const, (Ns + 1, 1), dtype=float)
```

Using this code on my machine, with an Ns = 1000, takes around 15.2 µs to generate P against 421 µs using your code (96% speed up).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to save calculating the values of the function more than once is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#targetText=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.) decorator. This trick will get you same result without the need to manually roll out your code.

```
def memoize(f):
    results = {}
    def helper(x,y):
        key = (float(x), float(y))
        if key not in results:
            results[key] = f(x,y)
        return results[key]
    return helper

@memoize
def D(p,r):
    return (      ( 1/(2*C01*(z-mu/r1)) )*(   ( 1/(2*(kappa1-C01*(z-mu/r1))) )*( E(2*(kappa1-C01*(z-mu/r1)),r)*E(2*C01*(z-mu/r1),p) )   -   ( 1/(2*kappa1) )*E(2*kappa1,r)   )      )
```